# How count all tags of XElement?

Tags: xpath

This is a `XElement`: `Dim oTaget=`:

```
<target xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1082">■ <x id="8746" /><g id="8747">Store the product ./g></mrk>
  <g id="8747">
    <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1083">For this purpose</mrk>
  </g>
</target>
```

I want count number tag `mrk`:

```
 Dim sentenchild As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
 sentenchild = oTaget.XPathSelectElements(dNS + ":mrk", namespaceManager)
 Return sentenchild.Count
```

But Result =1

How count all tags `mrk` of `oTaget`?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.//element` pattern to return *all* elements within a context element :

```
sentenchild = oTaget.XPathSelectElements(".//" + dNS + ":mrk", namespaceManager)
```

Quoted from [XPath 1.0 spec # 2.5 Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) :

> `.//para` selects the `para` element descendants of the context node

Another way is using [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
Dim dNS As XNamespace = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"
sentenchild = oTaget.Descendants(dNS + "mrk")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result count is one due to the `XPath` you set to select elements, which only counts the `mrk` elements which are in the first sub-level of `target`. You have to iterate recursively over all sub-elements of `target`.

**EDIT:**

Example for recursion in VB.NET see here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion-vbnet

Comment: Can not we select multi level?

Comment: No it's not possible. Use `XElement.Elements(XName)` to select the matching elements in every sub-level (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb348975(v=vs.110).aspx)